# Ruby on Rails - link_to button / css

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css

Ok so I am teaching myself RoR while developing a simple api & web interface.  I have been following a number of guides and testing out different outcomes.  I have mocked up some HTML templates and I am at the process where I am starting to strip them down into views.

In my HTML i have the following code, which is a Button with CSS styling:

```
 <input type="submit" name="" value="Add" id="open-contacts-dialog-btn" class="inbox-sf-add-btn tip" title="Open an dialog to add a new contact"/>
```

This is my button in my panel that I would like to link to the **/book/new/**, I know i need a **link_to** in here but what would my final code be?  The code I have tried is as follows

```
<%= link_to "Add", new_admin_course_path, :id=>"open-contacts-dialog-btn", :class=>"inbox-sf-add-btn tip" %>
```

But it is not adding my CSS styling, it is just generating the text "Add".  Any help would be useful. Thanks

Answer (score 89, accepted):

`link_to` generates a `<a>` tag, which is not `input type="submit"`. What you should use should be a `button_to`, which generates a form with a `input type="submit"` button to the link:

```
<%= button_to "Add", new_admin_course_path, :id => "open-contacts-dialog-btn",
      :class => "inbox-sf-add-btn tip", :method => :get %>
```

Note the `:method => :get`. Without it, the `button_to` will generate a form with method set to post.

Comment: This works, thank you.  People implementing Twitter Bootstrap should be aware that no <button> tag will generated for this form.  It's an <input>, instead, despite the ActionView helper name being button_to.  More info: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to

Answer (score 12):

I recently had to do this because my form was acting differently for link_to than it was with button_to and I needed the functionality the link provided. The best solution I found does not use CSS at all but instead calls .html_safe to escape the html in the ruby code and properly display the link as a button. What you want to do is this:

```
<%= link_to "<button>Add</button>".html_safe, new_admin_course_path, :id=>"open-contacts-dialog-btn", :class=>"inbox-sf-add-btn tip" %>
```

Comment: Just letting other Bootstrap users know that this will not work with a button in navbar as it places the css classes on the <a> tag rather than the <button> tag. I do note that the author of this solution was not dealing with Bootstrap so this does not mean the solution is invalid for other situations.

Comment: You can place the class on the <button> tag by adding it within the escaped HTML though... `<%= link_to "<button class='your-class-here'>Add</button>".html_safe, new_admin_course_path, :id=>"open-contacts-dialog-btn", :class=>"inbox-sf-add-btn tip" %>`

Answer (score 0):

*But it is not adding my CSS styling*
What do you mean? The link (`a` element) with classes `inbox-sf-add-btn` and `tip` is generated, right? So, what's the problem?

If you want strictly button (`input` element instead of `a`), you can specify `/book/new` (or `<%= new_admin_course_path %>`) in the `action` attribute of your html form (`form` element).