# Button_to tag in a form closes form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-3

I am currently working with form in ruby on rails 3. So in my project form I have a button to sign users out of this project. However, the strange thing is, that the `button_to` tag closes my whole form and i cannot use my submit button anymore.

So I tried a lot, but i do not understand why this happens.

So this is my form:

```
<%= form_for @project, html: { class: "form-horizontal project" } do |f| %>
    <div>
          <%= f.label :users, 'Project Users:',  :class => 'control-label', style: 'margin-bottom: 20px' %>
          <div>
            <% @project.users.order('last_name').each do |user| %>
                      <div style="margin-bottom: 15px">
                        <%= user.name %>
                          <%= button_to 'Sign Out', sign_user_out_project_path(user_id: user.id, id: @project), method: :delete, class: 'btn btn-danger btn-xs pull-right', style:'margin-right: 600px; margin-top: -20px' %>
                      </div>
            <% end %>
          </div>
        </div>


      <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
      <%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")),
                projects_path, :class => 'btn btn-default' %>

    <% end %>
```

In my opinion this code looks fine, as all tags are perfectly closed. However, i think there might be some magic when using `button_to` so maybe someone knows a better way to do what I want to do.

Thanks!

Comment: a button inside a form submits the form.  from your code, i don't see the point of the form at all as there are no other inputs like text field, select, checkbox, etc

Comment: there is more, i did not copy that part, as its not relevant for that question. So I cannot use button_to inside my form? What can i use instead? Could I use 'link_to'?

Comment: Why not a simple `link_to` ? As it is, you can straight up substitute `button_to` with `link_to` in your code and it should work right away.

Comment: yep just use a link_to

Comment: Thanks! It works now! But can you explain to me, why I cannot use button_to? Where is the big difference to link_to?

Comment: button_to creates a button tag. a button tag inside a form submits that form when clicked. link_to just creates an anchor tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't put a `button_to` inside your form.

As per the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to):

> (`button_to`) Generates a form containing a single button that submits to the URL created by the set of options

--

HTML forms have a [clear spec](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp), and you should adhere to that whenever you implement one.

Including a form within a form causes the "outer" form to stop working (HTML can't process another `<form>` before `</form>`.

---

The simple answer is to remove your `button_to` from within your form & put it outside, *or* (in your case), replace it with another element (`link_to`). If you want the link to look like a button, you can use [`<button>` markup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15695784/1143732) to create a button:

```
<%= form_for @project, html: { class: "form-horizontal project" } do |f| %>
    <div>
          <%= f.label :users, 'Project Users:',  :class => 'control-label', style: 'margin-bottom: 20px' %>
          <div>
            <% @project.users.order('last_name').each do |user| %>
                      <div style="margin-bottom: 15px">
                        <%= user.name %>   
                        <%= link_to '<button>Sign Out</button>'.html_safe, sign_user_out_project_path(user_id: user.id, id: @project), method: :delete, class: 'btn btn-danger btn-xs pull-right', style:'margin-right: 600px; margin-top: -20px' %>
                      </div>
            <% end %>
          </div>
        </div>

      <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
      <%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")),
                projects_path, :class => 'btn btn-default' %>

<% end %>
```