# Rails how to render collection inside form_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to render a collection of characters inside a form_for (so I can message multiple characters at once using `check_box_tag` inside each `character_item`). I'm using the following code but it is faulty. Only the first character is rendered inside the form, the rest appear outside the form. What am I doing wrong?

```
<%= form_for(:message, url: :messages, method: :post, html: { id: "message_form" }
            ) do |f| %>

  <% if characters.any? %>
    <% characters.each do |character| %>
      <%= render "characters/character", character: character, f: f %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

This produces the following html:

```
<form id="message_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/messages" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
  <div class="character_item" id="character_alfred">
</form>
<div class="character_item" id="character_barney">
<div class="character_item" id="character_chas">
<div class="character_item" id="character_dean">
```

EDIT

I've narrowed the problem down to this block of code. The layout is fine when I remove this:

```
<%= button_to destroy_relationship_path(
            params: {
              following_callsign: @character.callsign,
              followed_callsign: followedcallsign,
              viewed_callsign:  viewedcallsign
            }
          ),
          class: 'btn btn-default btn-xs post_button',
          id: 'unfollow-eye',
          remote: true,
          method: :delete do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sunglasses" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<% end %>
```

Can anyone see what's wrong with it? I suspect there isn't anything wrong with the button code, I think it's something to do with having a button inside a form. I don't know. I am, as usual, baffled.

Comment: can you add the '_character' partial code?  Something in there is ending the form_for.  Maybe because there are imbalanced tags or something.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you can't put a button inside a form, because it closes the form. See this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34644553/346613

The solution is to convert all the `button_to` into `link_to`.