# Using a button as a link in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, bootstrap-4

```
Rails 5
Bootstrap 4
Devise
```

I am trying to modify the `view/devise/registrations/edit.html.slim` view, by replacing the text link with a Bootstrap button for the delete and back actions. Will something like this work:

```
= link_to I18n.t 'devise.mailer.registrations.edit.cancel', registration_path(resource_name),  class: "btn btn-primary", data: { confirm: I18n.t 'devise.mailer.registrations.edit.confirm' }, method: :delete
= link_to I18n.t 'devise.mailer.registrations.edit.back', :back,  class: "btn btn-warning"
```

Comment: Try it and find out!

Comment: [make button tag as link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418004/ruby-on-rails-link-to-button-css) This would help you, you can modify it accordingly.

Comment: [make button tag as link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418004/ruby-on-rails-link-to-button-css) This would help you, you can modify it accordingly.

Comment: button_to does not work with bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

you need to nest the button tag inside `link_to` to do this. try this

```
= link_to registration_path(resource_name), data: { confirm: I18n.t 'devise.mailer.registrations.edit.confirm' }, method: :delete do
  button.btn.btn-primary
    = I18n.t 'devise.mailer.registrations.edit.cancel'
```